# Property id does not exist on type T typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'.
```

It comes at `row.original.id`

```
export interface ITable<T> {
  columns: any;
  data: T[];
  with_transition?: boolean;
  onClick?: (price_id: string) => void;
}

export default function Table<T extends object>({
  columns,
  data,
  with_transition,
  onClick
}: ITable<T>) {
  const {
    getTableProps, // table props from react-table
    getTableBodyProps, // table body props from react-table
    headerGroups, // headerGroups, if your table has groupings
    rows, // rows for the table based on the data passed
    prepareRow // Prepare the row (this function needs to be called for each row before getting the row props)
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody className={`${with_transition && 't-body-transition'}`} {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr className="transition" {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td onClick={() => onClick && row.original.id && cell.column.Header !== 'Button' && onClick(row.original.id)} className="transition" {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
}
```

Can anyone solve this issue? I want to use generic not static types.

Comment: How do you know it _will_ have an ID? Maybe you need to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could constrain your generic type to `{ id: string }`
or use a different approach by making your `onRowClick` function dynamic.

```js
export interface ITable<T> {
  ...,
  onRowClick?: [keyof T, (value: T[keyof T]) => void];
}

function Table<T>({
  ...,
  onRowClick
}: ITable<T>) {
  return (
    ...,
     <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
       {row.cells.map(cell => (
         <td  
            onClick={() => {
              if (onRowClick) {
                const [key, onClick] = onRowClick;

                onClick(row.original[key]);
              }
            }}>
            ...
          </td>
        ))}
     </tr>
  )
}
```

Use it by passing your key and onClick function.

```js
<Table 
  ...
  onRowClick={['price_id', yourRowClickFunction]}
/>
```